# Firing $watch event manually in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this code:

```
$scope.$watch('message', function()
{
    // the code
});
```

Is there any way to fire change event of message manually, so the code will be executed?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Few options:

1. Use $scope.$apply() to run the digest loop which call all of the watch expressions
2. Put you inner watch code inside a function and call it manually
3. Change `messages` :)

Answer (score 12):

Another option here is declaring the function separately and using `$scope.watch` with the pointer.

```
var watchFunction = function(){
    // the code
}

$scope.$watch('message',watchFunction);

watchFunction();
```

Comment: I find this solution (also the 2nd option in @ShaiRez answer) elegant and definitely more efficient than calling $scope.$apply()